# Localize app with jQuery.i18n

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization, internationalization

I would like to ask for your help about localizing my apps.
I need to translate some js files. For this I use jQuery.i18n.
My problem is that I could load my external resource file.
How can I correctly specify my path to one of my resource json files ?

[image]

And I try to load my specific resource string

[image]

I tried to used ~/Scripts... also ./Scripts...

but I could not load this json file.

Thanks

Krpo

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a relative file path. If you provide the layout of your file structure I can help further, but basically...

**Go back one folder:**

```
../Scripts/app/Localization/Resources/i18n/sk.json
```

**Go back two folders:**

```
../../Scripts/app/Localization/Resources/i18n/sk.json
```

**Go back three folers:**

```
../../../Scripts/app/Localization/Resources/i18n/sk.json
```

**Etc...**

Comment: Here is my location of Scripts folder on my local disk. c:\WORK\PROJECTS\My Current Project\1 client\client.web\Scripts\

Comment: I used relative path through "~" to reference my root folder ~/Scripts/bla bla bla and I debug JS and this library i18n called $.getJSON (url) which takes my path but it could not load this file. I dont understand why ..